# Can't access Pinia store in beforeEnter in vue 2 app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, pinia

I am using Pinia in a vue 2 app, and am trying to access some state in the beforeEach route guard, but receive the following error:

[image: pinia error]

I've followed the documentation here: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html, but I continue to get the same error.

I've also tried importing the pinia instance and providing it to `useAppStore` in `beforeEach`, but that doesn't seem to help either.

### routes/index.js

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import AlertInbox from '@/views/AlertInbox/main';
import AlertForm from '@/components/AlertForm/main';
import TextMessageForm from '@/components/TextMessageForm/main';
import AlertDetails from '@/views/AlertDetails/main';
import AlertSearch from '@/views/AlertSearch/main';
import AlertType from '@/components/AlertType/main';
import MMApp from '@/components/App/main';
import { useAppStore } from '@/stores/AppStore';

Vue.use(VueRouter);


const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: MMApp,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'alert',
        name: 'alertForm',
        component: AlertForm,
      },
      {
        path: 'alert/:id',
        component: AlertDetails,
        props: true,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'alertDetails',
            path: '',
            component: AlertType,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'text-message',
        name: 'textMessageForm',
        component: TextMessageForm,
        props: route => ({ customerId: route.query.customer })
      },
      {
        path: 'search/alerts',
        name: 'alertSearch',
        component: AlertSearch,
      },
      {
        path: ':filter',
        name: 'inbox',
        component: AlertInbox,
      },
    ]
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  base: "/",
  mode: "history",
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach(() => {
  const store = useAppStore();
  console.log(store.counts);
});

export default router;
```

### main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { createPinia, PiniaVuePlugin } from "pinia";

import App from "./App.vue";

import VueCompositionAPI from "@vue/composition-api";
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(PiniaVuePlugin);
const pinia = createPinia();

import router from "./router";


new Vue({
  router,
  pinia,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");

export default pinia;
```

Comment: Have you tried loading Pinia before the router in your main.js?  In the `new Vue({pinia, router,…})` call.

Comment: @Gabe Yes, I've tried that too, but no luck

Comment: "so my suspicion is this may be the root of the problem" - this is the most obvious problem, look no further it's fixed. "export default pinia" - don't do this in main, you're guaranteed to get circular dependencies in case you need pinia instance elsewhere, but generally you don't

Comment: @EstusFlask "this is the most obvious problem, look no further it's fixed." I'm not understanding how this fixes the issue - are you saying not to export pinia? Removing that export doesn't help, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Don't use incompatible router version. Don't export pinia from main, it's useless at least

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm using vue-router 3.5.5, which is working with pinia, I was just pointing out that the pinia docs reference methods from vue-router 4, which I'm not using.

Comment: It's tell you that you haven't done `app.use(pinia);`. So `const app = new Vue({ pinia, router, ... }); app.use(pinia);`

Comment: @StephenGilboy `app.use()` is not available in vue 2, but adding `Vue.use(pinia)` has resolved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Vue.use(pinia);` after `const pinia = createPinia();`